# Cypress async command confusion

Tags: cypress

```js
describe('Post Resource', () => {
  it('Creating a New Post', () => {
    cy.visit('/posts/new') // 1.

    cy.get("input.post-title") // 2.
      .type("My First Post"); // 3.

    cy.get("input.post-body") // 4.
      .type("Hello, world!"); // 5.

    cy.contains("Submit") // 6.
      .click(); // 7.

    cy.get("h1") // 8.
      .should("contain", "My First Post");
  });
});
```

This example is taken from the Cypress [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-To-Cypress). I'm struggling with 2 statements from the documentation about Cypress commands.

1. > Remember: Cypress commands are asynchronous and get queued for execution at a later time.
2. > Cypress guarantees that it will execute all of its commands and queries *deterministically* and identically every time they are run.

Using the example above there are 5 commands, they will all be enqueued and run "asynchronously" but yet "deterministically"?

Either each command is run in the order it was added to the queue and the next waits for the previous to complete or they all run asynchronously, i.e. independently of each other.

How do we ensure that "Hello, world!" is added to the post body before we click Submit for example unless the commands are actually run in sequence and synchronously?

Comment: They're asynchronous from the perspective of the `it` callback; think of a Cypress test as building a todo list, which is then given to someone else to work through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries like `cy.get()` are asynchronous, they repeat until the DOM satisfies the query or they timeout and the test stops. So `cy.get("input.post-body")` will keep checking the DOM until it finds that element.

The **command queue** is synchronous. One command or query has to complete and pass before the next one starts, which is why `.click()` on Submit does not happen until `.type("Hello, world!")` has finished.

Comment: Thank you Nicola. Maybe the first statement is where my confusion lies. I had asynchronous to mean that the command was running independently of other commands that might be running at the same time. Given only 1 command from the queue is running at any time, you seem to be saying the command is running asynchronously because it has the behaviour of retry-ability?

Comment: That's an accurate summary. I think the term asynchronous is used by Cypress to contrast with jQuery queries which don't retry, they can only resolve what's in the DOM at the time they run.